# update existing column with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Merge_Pr': ['BKK_AOT', 'BKK_BFS', 'BKK_TG', 'HND_ANA'],
                'UniqueName': ['PR1', 'PR2', 'PR3', 'PR18']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Merge_Pr': ['BKK_AOT', 'BKK_AOT','BKK_BFS', 'BKK_TG', 'BKK_TG','HND_ANA','HND_ANA'],
                'Quantity':[9240, 1433, 56779, 2230, 5560, 1004, 4553],
                'Requisition_Number': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',]})
```

I would like to update the column 'Requisition_Number' in df2 with values from the column 'UniqueName' by key column 'Merge_Pr' so the desired output would be :

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYZ5H.png)

I tried with merge but it creates a new column but I want to have the output in the existing one.
Thank you for any suggestions.
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try `map` or `merge` and assign the result to existing column

```py
df2['Requisition_Number'] = df2['Merge_Pr'].map(df1.set_index('Merge_Pr')['UniqueName'])
# or
df2['Requisition_Number'] = df2.merge(df1, on='Merge_Pr', how='left')['UniqueName']
```

```
print(df2)

  Merge_Pr  Quantity Requisition_Number
0  BKK_AOT      9240                PR1
1  BKK_AOT      1433                PR1
2  BKK_BFS     56779                PR2
3   BKK_TG      2230                PR3
4   BKK_TG      5560                PR3
5  HND_ANA      1004               PR18
6  HND_ANA      4553               PR18
```